# Determine its definiteness of the quadratic form $x^2_1 - 2x^2_2 + 5x^2_3 + 2x_1x_2 - 6x_2x_3$

Tags: determinant, quadratic-forms

The equation is the following: $x^2_1$ - 2$x^2_2$ + 5$x^2_3$ + 2$x_1$$x_2$ - 6$x_2$$x_3$

I thought about finding the definiteness through the positivity or negativity of eigenvalues. The first step was to converting the quadratic form into a matrix and I got the following:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & -2 & -3 \\
    0 & -3 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$

Then I decided to find the determinant of [A-λI], where I is identity matrix, and equalise it to 0:

$det\begin{bmatrix}
    1-λ & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & -2-λ & -3 \\
    0 & -3 & 5-λ
\end{bmatrix}=0$

The furthest simplification I could achieve was : $-λ^3+4λ^2+17λ-24=0$

But it is impossible to find λ without using some software.

Did I make a mistake somewhere? If not, which other method can I use to find the definiteness of the quadratic form?

Your replies are greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: What you are asking is in fact the *signature* of the quadratic form. There exists for that an algorithm based on the sign changes of the diagonal minors : see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1913478/305862).

Comment: By Sylvester's Law of Inertia,  there are two positive and one negative eigenvalues.$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach:

1. Find out the associated symmetric matrix.
2. Convert it to canonical form under congruence.
3. From the canonical form just by inspection you can find the definiteness.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).